# Symfony Fosuserbundle resend email

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I am trying to make a link that resends a confirmation token to a user after registering in Symfony3.

However, I get a deprecation message as follows:

> User Deprecated: The "fos_user.mailer" service is private, getting it
>   from the container is deprecated since Symfony 3.2 and will fail in
>   4.0. You should either make the service public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

Here is my controller:

```
public function resendActivationEmail($token, UserManagerInterface $userManager)
{
    $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);
    if (is_null($user)) {return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_registration_register');}
    $mailer = $this->get('fos_user.mailer');
    $mailer->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);
    return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_registration_check_email');
}
```

My services.yml:

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: truesubscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
```

I looked into the docs, it says that in Symfony3.4, services are private by default. I am using autowiring in my app, so how I get the `fos_user.mailer` without any deprecation warnings?

I tried setting Fosuserbundle services to public, doesnt help:

`services.yml`:

```
    ....
    FOS\UserBundle:
            public: true
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use DependencyInjection instead of call container directly. You should pass your mailer to your method:

```
public function resendActivationEmail($token, UserManagerInterface $userManager, \FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\MailerInterface $mailer)
{
    $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);
    if (is_null($user)) {return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_registration_register');}
    $mailer->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);
    return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_registration_check_email');
}
```

For more informations about dependencyInjection : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/injection_types.html

Comment: using it like you did (inject the interface from the method parameter) did not work. Symfony was throwing a cannot be null, $mailer expects a parameter exception. So i had to make a __constructor() for my controller and inject it there. It worked but I had never used/seen a __constructor in symfony controllers. I have always been using setContainer() instead. Do you think it is fine to use __constructor in controllers? Thank you so much btw!

Comment: Was looking at controllers in fosuserbundle, and saw that they use __constructor there, so that answered my question. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use `$mailer = $this->container->get('fos_user.mailer');`

instead of `$mailer = $this->get('fos_user.mailer');`

Comment: this works as well but GrenierJ's solution is probably a better way to go with. Thank you!